# Find E(X) from Moment Generating Function

Tags: probability, statistics, moment-generating-functions

> Let $$M(t)=\frac{5}{1-8t}$$ for $t<1/8$ be the mgf of random variable $X$. Find $E(X)$ and $Var(x)$.

I am not sure how to use the mgf to find the $E(X)$. Once I have the expected value I can find the variance.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why $M_X(0)\ne1$? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment-generating_function#Definition

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** For any $n\in \mathbb N$ $$E\left(X^{n}\right)=M_{X}^{(n)}(0)={\frac {d^{n}M_{X}}{dt^{n}}}(0)$$

Answer (score 3):

Find $E(X)=\frac{d}{dt}M(t)|_{t=0}$ and $E(X^{2})=\frac{d^{2}}{dt^{2}}M(t)|_{t=0}$. Sustitute these values into the definition of $Var(X)$.